# select all row and soft deleted row than been deleted before search date

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

so for the example i have this **article table**

```
+---------+----------------+------------+
| user_id |      post      | created_at |
+---------+----------------+------------+
|    0001 | some article   | 2018-01-01 |
|    0002 | other article  | 2018-01-01 |
|    0002 | some2 article  | 2017-10-01 |
|    0003 | some2 article  | 2017-10-01 |
+---------+----------------+------------+
```

and this article table have `belongsTo` relation ship to **user table**

```
+------+------+------------+
| id   | name | deleted_at |
+------+------+------------+
| 0001 | yo   | null       |
| 0002 | yea  | 2017-12-31 |
| 0003 | yes  | null       |
+------+------+------------+
```

so i want to return all article posted(created_at) at 2018-01-01 then it will return all the record like this

```
+---------+----------------+------------+
| user_id |      post      | created_at |
+---------+----------------+------------+
|    0001 | some article   | 2018-01-01 |
|    0002 | other article  | 2018-01-01 |
+---------+----------------+------------+
```

and now if i also don't want to include article from user that already have deleted_at value before or equal to 2018-01-01 then it will return

```
+---------+----------------+------------+
| user_id |      post      | created_at |
+---------+----------------+------------+
|    0001 | some article   | 2018-01-01 |
+---------+----------------+------------+
```

so far everything works fine now the other scenario that i asking in this question is if i take article at 2017-10-01 then it should be returning

```
+---------+----------------+------------+
| user_id |      post      | created_at |
+---------+----------------+------------+
|    0002 | some2 article  | 2017-10-01 |
|    0003 | some2 article  | 2017-10-01 |
+---------+----------------+------------+
```

because at that time user 0002 has not been deleted yet `user.deleted_at = 2017-12-31 vs article.created_at = 2017-10-01` and so on that date it should be included into the list.

how to get those result on the same query? so when i search the article with user that has not been deleted before the search date than it will shown but when i search the article with user that has been deleted after the search date then it won't show...

i tried

```
$table = Article::leftjoin('user','article.user_id','user.id')
->where('created_at',$search_date)
->whereNull('user.deleted_at')
->get();
```

will only showing article that user has deleted_at null value... but don;t know how to match the user deleted_at with the search date

Comment: If it was me, I'd forget about all the php/laravel/eloquent stuff for now, and instead focus on the sql. With that in mind, see [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$table = Article::leftjoin('user','article.user_id','user.id')
->where('created_at',$search_date)
->where(function($query) use($search_date) {
    $query->whereNull('user.deleted_at')
        ->orWhere('user.deleted_at', '<', $search_date);
})->get();
```

Comment: tried it and it won't return anything at all if i put the $search_date to 2018-01-01

Comment: Actually it should be > not <. Can you try with greater than operator?